# AsmSelectors not working with getCustomerSupportAgentTokenState

Tags: spartacus-storefront

```
import { AsmSelectors } from '@spartacus/core';
```

```
this.customerSupportAgentTokenStateSubscription = this.store
      .select(AsmSelectors.getCustomerSupportAgentTokenState)
      .subscribe((data) => {//code here}
```

Property 'getCustomerSupportAgentTokenState' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/storefront/node_modules/@spartacus/core/src/asm/store/selectors/asm-group.selectors")'.ts(2339)

Checked the official docs, didn't find anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selector `getCustomerSupportAgentTokenState` is no longer part of public API. To get token use `AuthStorageService.getToken` or `AsmAuthStorageService.getTokenTarget` to check if it belongs to CS agent.